# Petrick's Méthod With Maxterms

Tags: boolean-algebra

I recently learnt about Quine-McCluskey and Petrick's methods and they are all okay by me using minterms the procedure is as follows :

1- Reduce the prime implicant chart by eliminating the essential prime implicant rows and the corresponding columns.

2- Label the rows of the reduced prime implicant chart $P0,P1,P2,...Pn$

3- Form a logical function $P$ which is true when all the columns are covered. P consists of a product of sums where each sum term has the form $P_{i_0}+P_{i_1}+...+P_{i_n}$ where each $P_{i_j}$ represents a row covering column $i$

4- Reduce $P$ to a minimum sum of products by multiplying out and applying $X+XY=X$

5- Each term in the result represents a solution, that is, a set of rows which covers all of the minterms in the table. To determine the minimum solutions, first find those terms which contain a minimum number of prime implicants.

6- Next, for each of the terms found in step five, count the number of literals in each prime implicant and find the total number of literals.

7- Choose the term or terms composed of the minimum total number of literals, and write out the corresponding sums of prime implicants.

I have a problem I want to apply this same method but with essential prime implicants as Maxterms (POS expressions)
I really need someone to indicate the difference that will occur in each step

Thanks